# ignore HttpRequest Field for StreamReader

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, logging, .net-core

I want to ignore some field's in HttpRequest for StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync()
**Cause if I can't block it throws a big log**

For example:
My controller

```
    [HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit] 
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm] MyModel ysisFile)
        {
         //bla bla
        }
```

My request model

```
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string DocumentId { get; set; }
        public string DocumentType { get; set; }
        // i want to ignore this property
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    }
```

My log formater

```
    private async Task<string> FormatRequest(HttpRequest request)
        {
            // Leave the body open so the next middleware can read it.
            using var reader = new StreamReader(
                request.Body,
                encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
                detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false,
                leaveOpen: true);
            var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            // Do some processing with body…
            var formattedRequest = $"{request.Scheme} {request.Host}{request.Path} {request.QueryString} {body}";
            // Reset the request body stream position so the next middleware can read it
            request.Body.Position = 0;
            return formattedRequest;
        }
```

Comment: Probably this won't be possible the way you want it to be? That body stream is just a bunch of data, it's way before we'd start to talk about any sort of field or property. But if you use an action filter for logging, you can rely on the already bound model for example, instead of having to read the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve the problem exactly as I wanted.
But the problem was solved by removing the Body information completely :)

```
            var formattedRequest = $"{request.Scheme} {request.Host}{request.Path} {request.QueryString}";
```